# Уведомления пользователю в реальном времени. Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, websocket, redis

Возникла необходимость уведомлять юзера о событиях в системе в реальном времени.

Используется как основа laravel 5.3. Но как правильно это организовать и что для этого необходимо не знаю. Подскажите как правильно построить подобную систему. Возможно я смотрю не в ту сторону но все что я пока что нашел это [Events в laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events)

2 типа уведомлений:

1. Письма
2. Сообщение на фронте в виде окна с текстом.

Comment: какие события в системе?  каким методом хотите уведомлять юзера?

Comment: @Arsen для разных событий по разному. Вообще пока что должно быть 2 вида 1е письма 2е уведомление на фронте в виде окна с сообщением

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/real-time-laravel-with-socket-io/episodes/1

Comment: @Orange_shadow 9 баксов в месяц для второго урока( Но суть я уловил

Comment: Поищи на трекерах например тут rutracker.cr

Comment: @Orange_shadow  не знаешь готовые решения или пример проекта уже с использованием ноды и лары хочется именно структуру приложения увидеть.

Comment: именно с soket.io оповещениями нет, то там все просто, там события создаешь,  даешь им особенность  Broadcasting, и понеслось, вообще есть Урок полный от Teo Otwela

Comment: Вот тут на халяву :) видео https://laracasts.com/lessons/broadcasting-events-in-laravel-5-1

Comment: @Orange_shadow не приходилось самому организовывать с нуля мне ноду самому руками чтоли каждый раз запускать на серваке

Comment: Зачем каждый раз ? это как сервис, запустил и все, ты ж Апач руками каждый раз не запускаешь

Comment: Скажу, что есть сокет.ио, для его интеграции с бекендом можно использовать elephant.io для выброса событий в сокет.ио, и любое хттп апи для взаимодействия сокет.ио с бекендом (в ларавеле рест очень легко пилится). Помимо этого есть решения на пхп, такие как ratchet, workerman. Их преимущество - воркеры поднимаются как консольные приложения, удобнее работать с беком. Есть так же сторонние сервисы.

Comment: тема интересная и все на ноде вяжется) потом сделаю конкурс по вопросу наверное так как еще нет ни одного ответа

Comment: @Shadow33, ну вообще я реализовал это все, очень тесно с двумя такими проектами работаю. Разве что истинно православного способа на ларавеле не знаю, так как работаю не с ним. Но все мною перечисленное проверено на практике в связках с yii и phalcon. Куча всего крутится, от чатов до игровых серверов. Попробуй, пока ждешь однозначного ответа.

Comment: @DanielOlivo да все это определенно перепробую.  Мне бы лучше посмотреть на саму структуру приложения. А стек что использовать уже подсказали. Спасибо )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В двух словах абстрагировано, добавляете методы которые проверяют информацию при появлении которой нужно выдать уведомление.
К примеру

```html
public function newMessage()
    {
      // проверяем...
      //если есть новое
      setcookie("newMessage", $count, time() + 86400);
                return 'yes';
      //если нет
        return 'no';
                
    }
```

Добавляем маршрут к этому методу.
На фронте c помощью ajax слушайте эти куки.

```js
<script>
+        function newMsg(data, d){if(data == "yes"){
+            $('.new-msg').css('display', 'block');
+        }}
+        setInterval(function(){
+            $.ajax({
+                url: "/new-message",
+                type: "POST",
+                data: ({popupMsg: "go"}),
+                dataType: "html",
+                success: newMsg
+            });
+        },300000) 
 </script>
```

Как то так...

Answer (score 3):

Делал себе что-то подобное, реализовал следующим образом:

1. Уведомления Email, SMS и т.п. лучше всего сделать через новую возможность, которая появилась в версии 5.3: [Laravel Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications)

Если в будущем захотите не только Email уведомление ознакомьтесь с сайтом - http://laravel-notification-channels.com/ там есть много каналов для уведомлений.

2. Уведомления в браузере лучше всего тоже реализовать через новую фичу версии 5.3: [Event Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting)

Начнем с того что выберем [драйвер](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#driver-prerequisites) для Event Broadcasting, я покажу на примере [Pusher](https://pusher.com/).

Для начала внесем изменения в файл .env:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher

PUSHER_APP_ID=#данные с панели Pusher
PUSHER_KEY=#данные с панели Pusher
PUSHER_SECRET=#данные с панели Pusher
```

Загрузим пакет через Composer:

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```

Пока с Pusher всё, в конце вернемся к нему ещё раз.

Создаем событие, (примеры и описание есть [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/broadcasting#defining-broadcast-events)) к примеру мы будем отправлять уведомление когда кто-то пишет пользователю. 
Объект уведомления будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ChatMessageSend implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
    * @var User
    */
    public $user;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, array $data)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['chat-channel'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'message-received';
    }
}
```

Методы broadcastOn и broadcastAs нужны для Event Broadcasting, так же надо создать Listener для этого события чтобы в нём отправлять Email сообщение и прочие.

Теперь необходимо создать [Mail Notification](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/notifications#mail-notifications) в котором укажем шаблон письма, пример доступен по ссылке, назовем его к примеру MessageSend.

Далее нужно создать Listener который будет вызывать это уведомление:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\ChatMessageSend;
use App\Notifications\MessageSend;

class SendChatMessageNotification
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  ChatMessageSend  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ChatMessageSend $event)
    {
        $event->user->notify(new MessageSend($event->data));
    }
}
```

Теперь файле `EventServiceProvider` привяжем событие и слушатель:

```
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\ChatMessageSend' => [
        'App\Listeners\SendChatMessageNotification',
    ],
];
```

Теперь всё готово для отправки уведомлений.
Чтобы отправить уведомление нужно вызвать событие:

```
event(new ChatMessageSend($user, $data));
```

Письмо на почту ушло, и ушло на сервис Pusher, но теперь надо его вывести в браузере, на сайте Pusher есть примеры для разных языков, я выведу для JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title>Pusher Test</title>
  <script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.0/pusher.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('key', {
      cluster: 'eu',
      encrypted: true
    });

    var channel = pusher.subscribe('chat-channel');
    channel.bind('message-received', function(data) {
      alert(data.data);
    });
  </script>
</head>
```

Вместо alert пишите свой JS для уведомлений в браузере.

P.S. Код должен быть рабочий, но мог где то что-то пропустить